# cpanel password change

Tags: passwords, cpanel

I need to change my Cpanel password (currently the Root and standard user passwords are the same and as such limiting access).

If I change my password and leave the 'Allow MySQL password change' checkbox ticked, will I need to alter my Wordpress configuration in any way so it can continue to access and modify my MySQL database.

Cheers,

Dan

Answer (score 3):

If you leave the 'Allow MySQL password change' checkbox ticked, you will also change the MySQL password for the main MySQL user (that has same username as you cPanel username).

Leaving this checkbox ticked will NOT change the MySQL password for the MySQL users you have created in the MySQL cPanel section.

If you haven't created MySQL user for your Wordpress database and if you used the main MySQL user instead, then yes, you will have to update your Wordpress configuration.

If you do not leave the checkbox ticked, then clicking PHPMyAdmin under cPanel will not log you in automatically and you will have to enter your cPanel username and your OLD password to access PHPMyAdmin or you can use some other MySQL username and password that you created using the MySQL cPanel section.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are confused whether you need to update the wordpress database user's password, the answer is No. 
While updating the cPanel password by ticking 'Allow MySQL password change' will not affect any database user created in the cPanel before, it will only change the main cpanel user mysql account password.